# Is it possible to copy from int** to another int** but not element by element?

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix, copy

I have a n x n matrix stored in  int** matrix1.
I have another int** matrix2 with m x m dimensions with m > n.
I'd like to copy the first matrix in the top left corner of the second one and fill in the missing locations from n+1 to m.
Is there any other way than copying element by element?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  memcpy ( matrix2[i], matrix1[i], n*sizeof(int));
}
```

and then fill in the missing locations

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
matrix2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  matrix1[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
}
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
  matrix2[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
}

// assigning some random values
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        matrix1[i][j] = j;
    }
}

// copying elements using memcpy
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  memcpy ( matrix2[i], matrix1[i], n*sizeof(int));
}
```